# Exclude a URL from folder redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting all URLs from `www.example.com/forums` to `www.example.com/blog/`.

so I made this rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^forums blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the thing is that I want to exclude some URLs that also begin with `forums/` and redirect them to particular URL other than `/blog`.

For example, `forums/8/some-made-up-word-here-1681` to `/studies/some-made-up-studies`.

Right now, it redirects to `/blog` like all URLs that start with `forum/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the more specific redirects first, before the more general rule. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Specific redirects
RewriteRule ^forums/8/some-made-up-word-here-1681 /studies/some-made-up-studies [R,L]

# Redirect all other URLs that start /forums
RewriteRule ^forums/?(.*) /blog/$1 [R,L]
```

I've also modified your existing directive to redirect `/forums/<something>` to `/blog/<something>`, which I assume was perhaps the original intention, since you were using a `$1` backreference in the *substitution*, but did not have a capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Your original directive would have redirected `/forums/<something>` to `/blog/`.

I've also included a slash prefix on the *substitution*. This is required for redirects, although you may have set `RewriteBase` instead, in which case you do not need to do this.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the earlier catch-all 301 will have been cached hard by the browser. For this reason it is often easier to test with temporary 302s in order to avoid the caching problem. Change the above temporary redirects to 301s only after you have confirmed this is working as intended.

**UPDATE:** To redirect all URLs that start `/forums` to `/blog/`, without copying the remainder of the URL, then change the last directive to read:

```
# Redirect all other URLs that start /forums
RewriteRule ^forums /blog/ [R,L]
```

Basically, the `$1` in your original directive was superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, before i try your code i want to mention that i also redirect /forums without the forward slash to /blog/...not only /forums/ and follows it

Comment: Yes, that is OK, the pattern `^forums/?(.*)` will match just `/forums` as well. The `?` makes the preceding slash optional.

Comment: sorry, but i need all URLs that follow forums/ to redirect to /blog/ only (no trailing) except the one I mentioned. right now with your code, anything that follows /forums brings 404 page because it forwards to /blog/same-following-content/

Comment: Hi MrWhite, the  code in this solution worked when i tried it but now it doesn't work for me any longer...maybe i was quick too judge that it is working...not sure. is there a way to contact you and give you the code and the actual URL so you can help me?

Comment: Add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question (assuming you only have the one `.htaccess` file in the root of your filesystem). State the URLs being requested and the desired outcome. The most probable cause is a conflict with another directive.